# Is it possible to run a unit test on a celery periodic task?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, celery

I'm trying to run a unit test on a celery task that I have set to run daily.
I have tried importing the function and calling it in my test but this doesn't work.

The task is:

```
@shared_task

def create_a_notification_if_a_product_is_in_or_out_of_season():
    """
    Send a notification if a product is now in or out of season
    """
    julian_date = date.today().timetuple().tm_yday + 1
    active_products = Product.objects.filter(status='ACTIVE')

    for products in active_products:
        in_season_prd = ProductDescription.objects.filter(
            product=products, 
            early_start_julian=julian_date
        )
        for prd in in_season_prd:
            notification = Notification()
            notification.type = notification_choices.PRODUCT_IN_SEASON
            notification.description = str(prd.product.name) + " will be in season from tomorrow."
            notification.save()
```

and here is an example of one of my tests:

```
def test_when_product_is_about_to_come_in_to_seasonality(self):
    """
    Make a notification when a product is due to come in to seasonality tomorrow
    """
    p = Product.objects.first()
    p.status = "ACTIVE"
    today = date.today().timetuple().tm_yday
    p.early_start_julian = today + 1
    create_a_notification_if_a_product_is_in_or_out_of_season()
    updated_notifications = Notification.objects.all().count()
    self.assertNotEqual(self.current_notifications, updated_notifications)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`apply()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply) your celery task to execute it synchronously:

```
def test_when_product_is_about_to_come_in_to_seasonality(self):
    """
    Make a notification when a product is due to come in to seasonality tomorrow
    """
    p = Product.objects.first()
    p.status = "ACTIVE"
    today = date.today().timetuple().tm_yday
    p.early_start_julian = today + 1
    create_a_notification_if_a_product_is_in_or_out_of_season.apply()
    updated_notifications = Notification.objects.all().count()
    self.assertNotEqual(self.current_notifications, updated_notifications)
```

Comment: I've tried this and I have the same result where the task isn't run which should create a notification and therefore when I compare self.current_notifications with updated_notification they are still equal and the test fails

Comment: I've realised that the reason this was still failing was due to the factory I had set up which created the products to run the tests on. Adding .apply() to the end of the imported task does work though and the task is firing. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help @BenCurrie :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` setting. If set to `True` it will run your tasks synchronously. You can set it in your test settings or you can decorate only that test with `@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)`

Comment: I just tried this but it still doesn't seem to be running the task as no notification is created and the test fails. Thanks anyway though